# How can i get work and age from Facebook iOS API

Tags: ios, facebook, fbsdkloginkit

I am trying to get some data from Facebook and I am able to get is:

```
[[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:@{ @"fields" : @"id,name,first_name,last_name,picture.width(300).height(300),gender,birthday"}]startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {

NSString *nameOfLoginUser = [result valueForKey:@"name"];
                fNameUser = [result valueForKey:@"first_name"];
                lNameUser = [result valueForKey:@"last_name"];
                genderUser = [result valueForKey:@"gender"];
                ageUser = [result valueForKey:@"birthday"];

                NSString *imageStringOfLoginUser = [[[result valueForKey:@"picture"] valueForKey:@"data"] valueForKey:@"url"];
}
```

how can I get "age" and "work at" from API.

Comment: age is not a big deal i can calculate that but work i am not getting it. i tried with "work" in fields but no response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get age as you can access birthday and there is no paramter related age ... so you need to calculate age according to birthday ..

**For work:** you can access work only after reviewing your app.

> If your app requests this(work) permission Facebook will have to review how your app uses it.

For more datail check out [this doc.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions#reference-user_work_history)